# Having issues with Vbus and Vcc on my project board

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am trying to power my board with the Vbus from a mini usb connector, but EAGLE won't let me connect the Vbus to the VCC wire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are two different nets: VBUS and VCC. Eagle is protecting you from shorting these two.

Check your schematic - there is at least one component between VBUS and VCC.

Comment: fixed it thanks!